# IOS detect when user stops touching UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, touch-event

Any idea how to do this? I have a `UIImageView` inside of each **cell** in my `UITableView` and I want to disable scroll when the user starts touching the `UIImageView` and then enable it once the user stops dragging their finger on the photo.

Comment: In order to do this, you would probably want to add a UITapGestureRecognizer onto the image view. For disabling the scroll, you could try tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: but what gesture recognizer detects when a user stops touching? i can get the tableview to disable scrolling when a user is touching , i just cant get it to enable it when they stop touching

Comment: You could do a boolean operation on that, but I strongly suggest doing what @The King has shown below

Answer (score 3):

I just give my logic.

Add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to each cell of `UITableView.`

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

And in method name is `handlePanFrom:`

```
 - (void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer 
{

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:recognizer.view];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
      /// track began
      tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;    
    } 
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
    {
        // track the movement
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {
        //  final position
        tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
 }
```

**Make sure your `UIIMageView` must be set as a `userInteractionEnabled = YES;`.** Because by default `UIIMageView` have to set `userInteractionEnabled = NO;.`

Comment: ehh i think your closer than i was but this creates a new set of problems . it will probably help for you to see the context this is being used in. See my image ive added to my post. With your solution the user can no longer wipe the photo off fluidly

Comment: Ya, its because if you set the tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; then all its sub views will stop detecting user interaction. So use tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: Even with scrollEnabled its still completely ruins the ability to fluidly swipe the photo off the screen in one big touch/drag event like a eraser in photo shop. ScrollDisabled is the key though i think bc if i add scroll disabled to the delegate method that enables the erasing it works exactly the way i want it to , the only problem is i have no way to re-enable it once the user is done erasing the img

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to implement this, either include `UITapGestureRecognizer` or  `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView` and set the target and action where target is your custom UITableViewCell class or include

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

methods in the `UIImageView` custom class and set the delegate via protocol to your custom `UITableViewCell`.

for `UIGestureRecognizer` you can check its state property [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIGestureRecognizerState) to know the state with the help of switch

```
typedef enum {
   UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible,

   UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded,
   UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled,

   UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed,

   UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
}
```

Finally, by toggling the UITableView's scrollEnabled property to stop and start scrolling where `UITableView` is a sub class of `UIScrollView`

Comment: @The King, may I know the reason why?

Comment: not really clear on how to put this solution to use ,excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @ChuckKelly, More or less me and The King are saying the same thing but I am giving an abstract answer and he is giving concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO");
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: are these suppose to go in my imageviewclass?

Comment: No. your `viewController` class

Comment: But touchesEnded is raised when you release your finger.